# Difficulties understanding $\Delta E_1= 0$ in first order perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am currently learning about perturbation theory.
One example we had in class was the 1d quantum harmonic
oscillator with a static electrical field as a perturbation.

$
H_1 = qE\hat{x}
$

It follows from symmetry, that the first order energy correction
term is zero. But contrary to my first intuition that does not mean
that the first order correction to the wave function is zero as well.
As the correction to the wave function I get:

$
\vert\phi_n^{1}\rangle \propto (\sqrt(n)\vert n-1\rangle - \sqrt(n+1)\vert n+1 \rangle)
$

Which should be correct.
Now, as the energy of the first order correction is zero I expect
the energy of $\vert\phi\rangle = \vert\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle + \vert\phi_n^{(1)}\rangle$
w.r.t the full Hamiltonian $H_0 + H_1$ to be the same as the energy of the unperturbed state w.r.t the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H_0$
But if I try to calculate $\langle\phi\vert H_0 + H_1\vert\phi\rangle$ I do not get the same as $\langle\phi_n^{(0)}\vert H_0 \vert\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle$.

Did I misunderstood something would you expect
$\langle\phi\vert H_0 + H_1\vert\phi\rangle = \langle\phi_n^{(0)}\vert H_0 \vert\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle$ as well?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. However, when you calculate $\left< \phi_n\right| H_0 + H_1 \left| \phi_n\right>$ to *first-order* corrections in the state, be sure to throw away terms that are second-order or higher in the perturbation. You should find the same energy as $\left< \phi_n^{(0)}\right| H_0 \left| \phi_n^{(0)}\right>$, after keeping only terms that are first-order in the perturbation or smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed all the "unexpected" terms are proportional to $q^2$ and therefor would be neglected!